# Page indexing is not working on 2nd page onwards

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Paging is not working in my grid view. When I click to 2nd page it not working

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVPending" DataKeyNames="Userid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="GVPending_PageIndexChanging"  EnableViewState="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void GVPending_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GVPending.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GVPending.DataBind();
    // bind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind the database table you can't leave it as empty. so code should be like this

```html
GVPending.DataSource = database;
GVPending.DataBind();
```